# Find the limit $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {\frac{1}{n^{\alpha+1}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i^\alpha}} $ where $\alpha \ge0$.

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, summation

Find the limit $ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {\frac{1}{n^{\alpha+1}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i^\alpha}} $  where $\alpha \ge0$.

I have shown that when $ \alpha=0$, the limit is 1. How to proceed when  $ \alpha>0$ ?

Comment: It's just a Riemann sum as shown below.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Stoltz  theorem to see that the limit is the same as
$$\frac{(n+1)^{\alpha}}{(n+1)^{\alpha+1}-n^{\alpha+1}}\rightarrow \frac{1}{\alpha +1}.$$

Comment: It's a good suggestion +1.  Presumably one uses $(n+1)^{\alpha +1} - n^{\alpha +1} = n^{\alpha +1}[(1 + 1/n)^{\alpha +1} -1] = n^\alpha n [1 + (1+\alpha)/n + O(1/n^2) - 1] = n^\alpha[ 1 + \alpha + O(1/n)]$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the Riemann sum.

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {\frac{1}{n^{\alpha+1}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i^\alpha}}
 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{(i/n)^\alpha}} = \int_0^1 x^\alpha \, dx $$